# How to subtract two columns with different length only if other column has the same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, subtraction

I have two df.

df1 has two columns where the first one is an identifier and the second one is a value. The total length of df is 1071.

df2 has multiple columns but also have one column as identifier and other as value. The total length of df2 is 500000.

I want to write a program where I create a new column in df2 where in each  record I have the result of df2['value']-df['value] if df2['identifier']==df1['identifier'].
I have this but i know that it does not make sense:

```
if df1['identifier'] == df2['identifier']:
    df2['new_value']= df2['value']-df1['value']
else:
    pass
```

I got the following error: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?

```py
df2 = df2.merge(df1, how="outer", on="identifier")
df2["new_value"] = df2["value_y"] - df2["value_x"]
```

First, merge the two data sets on the `identifier` column, then subtract. If the identifier is not present in `df1`, then `NaN` is returned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer It was very helpful.
I copy the first part but the second line has the following error: Key error: 'value'
I solved mixing your solution with mine:

df2 = df2.merge(df1, how="outer", on="identifier")
def x(a,b):
    return a - b

df2['new_value']  = df2.apply(lambda f: x(f['Value_x'],f['value_y']), axis=1)
Thanks again, you help a lot in order to find the solution

Comment: It means that the value column is not included in the dataframe. When you merge the dataframes, can you print a list of the columns of you obtain?